# React/CSS: why does my <p> tag move its parent <div> on mobile?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, jsx

I am writing a React app that's mobile first. MY div alignment seemed to be normal on Firefox Dev Tools iPhone screen but when I launched my app, the alignment is erratic. Seems like it's due to the height of the `<p>` element or its # of lines. I know this because it was happening on PC too but I fixed it by setting the p element to a fixed height. If someone has any ideas as to why it is happening and if there is a fix, please let me know, it'll be greatly appreciated!

Here is screenshot of iPhone mobile:
[iphone mobile frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNzjL.jpg)

Here is screenshot of PC on Mozilla Firefox Webdev tools:
[PC Mozilla Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H17FP.png)

Here is my css:

```css
.card {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: solid 3px #dddddd;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}

.card:hover{
    border: outset 4px #dddddd;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    cursor: grab;
}

.card:active{
    cursor: grabbing;
}

.card img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:10%; 
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.card span{
    background-color:limegreen;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.card-p{
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #45505c;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;

  }

.container{
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 80%;
}

.container h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

Here is my React JSX

```js
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <h2>{props.questionData.question}</h2>
      <div className='card-container'>
        {
          props.questionData.options.map((option,index)=>(            
          <div className={'card'} onClick={()=>handleClick(props.questionData.question,option.text)}  key={index}>
          <img src={option.iconPath} alt='icon'/>
          <p className='card-p'>{option.text}</p>
      </div>))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Edit: People are asking for pure html, here it is copied from Firefox inspect element...Also included the stylesheet in the same snippet. Thanks in advance!

```css
.card {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: solid 3px #dddddd;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}

.card:hover{
    border: outset 4px #dddddd;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    cursor: grab;
}

.card:active{
    cursor: grabbing;
}

.card img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:10%; 
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.card span{
    background-color:limegreen;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.card-p{
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #45505c;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;

  }

.container{
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 80%;
}

.container h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Great! What type of property are you refinancing?</h2>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/static/media/0-1.400fe52e.svg" alt="icon">
      <p class="card-p">Single Family Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/static/media/0-2.f2e4dfe1.svg" alt="icon">
      <p class="card-p">Town Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/static/media/0-3.bc78fdb6.svg" alt="icon">
      <p class="card-p">Condominium</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/static/media/0-4.5d3ec9ae.svg" alt="icon">
      <p class="card-p">Multi Family Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/static/media/0-5.7a491458.svg" alt="icon">
      <p class="card-p">Manufactured or Mobile Home</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance of a [MCVE] with the html as rendered by recact?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the rendered HTML instead of the React code?

Comment: Could be a result of the screen width. The mozilla devtools phone seems to have a larger width than your phone. Try using devtools to narrow the width of your screen and see if it reproduces the problem.

Comment: @JoeJohnson Yes its responsive, when I decrease width it collapses to 1 column from 2 that you see

Comment: @JonP done, check it out

Comment: @DanMullin check it out, I edited in

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using `inline-block` for the cards.

Since there are two lines of text, the `inline-block` elements line up on the baseline of the text. You'll notice that the bottom line of text is aligned on the ones up higher.

A simple fix is to add these lines to your `.card-container`

```css
.card-container {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

The display mode is ignored for child items of a flex container. You can remove the `display: inline-block` from the `.card` if you go with this solution.

Something else to note about `inline-block` is that it doesn't ignore white space. When using `inline-block` elements, these two snippets will produce different results.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed it Thank you!